Treatment of conversion of empty strings for decimal datatype vs int
I've encountered that conversion doesn't work for variables of type decimal in SQL Server when dealing with an empty string, unlike for other data types such as int and datetime where it does work. What could be the reason for this, and where can I find the complete rules?
declare @val decimal(18,2)
set @val = ''
select @val
--Error 8114 - "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

declare @val bigint
set @val = ''
select @val
--return 0

declare @dt datetime
set @dt = ''
select @dt
--return 1900-01-01


You can get the same behaviour by assigning it 0 instead.

@shawnt00 - It is perfectly valid to cast strings to decimal - e.g. CAST('5.3' AS DECIMAL(2,1)) the question is about special casing of the empty string.

There could be any number of reasons why some empty strings can be converted to a given datatype. and others fail. These are edge cases for sure and would likely need to be answered by the engineers at MS who made those decisions many years ago. I don't know that I have ever seen a list of valid conversions from an empty string to a datatype.

@SeanLange probably Sybase rather than MS. I imagine this was some dubious design decision made early on that is preserved for backwards compatibility, maybe decimal was a later addition and they had thought better of it by then but finding documentation for these early editions has always eluded me

@shawnt00 - It was definitely there before that (this post from 1995 mentions it in SQL Server 6.0) https://groups.google.com/g/comp.databases.ms-sqlserver/c/pvaFnju-_w4/m/SaliuejocUoJ

You're gonna have a bad time converting sql server quirks to another db vendor, wouldn't it be better to setup some invariants for the procedure to reject and then simplify the code? Unless you're writing some kind of clone of Aurora babelfish aws

Just use ISNULL(TRY_CAST(.... AS decimal(18,2)), 0)

This works (almost) according to the documentation. The set of rules for string conversions is here.
For empty string, there are rules for int and date only:

When an empty string gets converted to an int, its value becomes 0. When an empty string gets converted to a date, its value becomes the date - which is 1900-01-01

bigint is not mentioned. But according to my tests, bigint, smallint and tinyint all share the same rule with int.
And there is no such rule for numeric.

Just for completeness - A CAST of an empty string to any of the following will yield a zero or equivalent: bit, tinyint, int, bigint, smallint, real, float, money, smallmoney, datetime, smalldatetime, datetime2, date, time, datetimeoffset, timestamp. A CAST of an empty string to any of the following will throw an error, and a TRY_CAST will yield a null: numeric, decimal, uniqueidentifier, geography, geometry, hierarchyid. Both CAST and TRY_CAST of an empty string to xml will throw an error.  An CAST or an empty string to any character type or sql_variant naturally succeeds,

So, numeric and decimal do kind of stand out amongst the other numeric types.  fiddle
